# Domain Setup Debacle

Tags: remote-desktop, domain-name

I'm a newby - so go easy on me please :)

I have a Win 2003 Server at home, and I want to register a domain name so that I can access it remotely. I have seen other companies using server.domainname.com.au to access via RDP.

How do I go about this, I've been looking around for some help with this but all of the domain stuff is a bit confusing to me to know where to start looking.

Thanks muchly.

Newbie.

Comment: I think you meant to say "debacle" right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't need to register for a domain name if this is solely for your own remote access purposes. Since you probably don't have a static IP at home, you want to use a dynamic DNS service like [dyndns](http://dyndns.org).

Answer (score 3):

Free way: use a dynamic dns name. Sites like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/)  will let you set up a hostname like yourname.dyndns.org. You would install their client on your system so that whenever your IP address changes, they update the user-friendly name.